# Angularjs interpolateprovidor not working in IE9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I just want to use different interpolator for rendering bound values in HTML page.. 
But in IE9 browser, my interpolators `<% %>` are not working at all ...

I have created a fiddler [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/wkcd29mn/)

Please help me resolving this issue..

regards
Ram

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If my answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted by clicking the accept checkmark to the left of the question (this will also earn you some reputation). Let me know if you need some more information/help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 will interpret any symbol starting with `<` as a tag, which means that you will have to use other symbols if you want this to work on IE9.

You could try soomething like `((` `))` instead.

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4o8zvu1e/1/)